# Django forcing encoded text when calling third party api

Tags: c, django, python-2.7, character-encoding, cython

I posted a question similar to this last week and didnt get many responses so I will try to post it again with a better explanation.

I am running a django web app on ubuntu 11.04 and using cython/pyrex to call a third party C api.

After compiling all the necessary files in order to be able to call the C api from python, I decided to run a standalone python script to make sure it works. After a little testing I was able to get it run correctly. I am able to print and retrieve the necessary information from the C api by calling it from python.

Here is the Cython/Pyrex code that is being used along with python to call the C api:

get_params.pyx:

```
cimport cste
ctypedef signed int int32_t
ctypedef signed int int16_t


cdef class CEngineApi:

cdef cste.ste_handle* _ste_handle

def __cinit__(self, path):
    self._ste_handle = cste.ste_init(path)

def __dealloc__(self):
    pass

def ste_get_all_params(self):
    cdef char stateC[3]
    cdef char countyC[4]
    cdef char cityC[7]
    call_ok = cste.ste_get_all_params(self._ste_handle, stateC, countyC, cityC)
    return stateC, countyC, cityC
```

cste.pxd:

```
from libc.stddef cimport wchar_t, size_t
ctypedef unsigned short uint16_t
ctypedef signed int int32_t
ctypedef signed int int16_t

cdef extern from "ste.h":

    ctypedef struct ste_handle:
        pass

    ste_handle* ste_init(const char *path)

    uint16_t ste_get_all_params (const ste_handle * ste,  
                                 char * stateCode, 
                                 char * countyCode, 
                                 char * cityCode)
```

Here is my standalone python script which returns the correct params after making the call to the api get_param_test.py:

```
from cenginelib import CEngineApi
import os

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
CENGINE_LIBARY_PATH=os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'ste-root' )

engine = CEngineApi(CENGINE_LIBARY_PATH)

state_code, county_code, city_code = engine.ste_get_all_params()
print "State code : %s" % (state_code)
```

Note: when i compile the code for the C api, cenginelib.so is created which is why I am importing CEngineApi in from it.

However, when i run the python script above it runs correctly like i said and spits out : 
"State code : 36"

I tried to print out all three numbers originally but for debugging reasons I am just trying to get this single number returned during runtime inside my django app.

Now, the code used inside of my django app where I call the C api is almost identical but to avoid confusion I will add it anyhow.

settings.py is where i instantiate the api:

```
from cenginelib import CEngineApi
import os

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
CENGINE_LIBARY_PATH=os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'ste-root' )

CAPI_engine = CEngineApi(CENGINE_LIBARY_PATH)
.....
```

here is a method on my model where i call the api:

```
from django.conf import settings
def ste_get_all_params_method(self):
    stC, countyC, cityC = settings.CAPI_engine.ste_get_all_params()
    return stC
```

lastly, here is my template where i call this model method in order to try to get it to show the api output on the front end, param_template.html:

```
<ul>
      <li>
          {{pay_model.ste_get_all_params_method}}
      </li>
</ul>
```

The error that is returned from django is DjangoUnicodeDecodeError:

```
Exception Value: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 2: invalid start byte. You passed in '\xc5\x99\x9c\x01' (<type 'str'>)
```

Note: the error may be formatted slightly different because the error was sent to my email from the server.

I have tried everything I can think of to try to fix this including using encode(), decode(), from django.utils.encoding among many other things. If you could give me an idea of how to fix this or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. I have read everything I can find online and still no solution. Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: I got lost, I don't in what line of code you're getting the exception. Can you post a traceback or something?

Comment: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py in force_unicode, line 93" is at the top of the traceback list in the email. The error occurs when trying to render the information returned  from the c api on the front end.

Comment: Do you know how that information returned from c api is encoded? Is it a string I guess? Which characters is using?

Comment: it should be returning a string. How can i determine what encoding it is using?

Comment: Well, what's the logic behind the method in C? Do you retrieve this string from a file or a database, try to return a dummy string with only ascii chars to test it.

Comment: i tried to return a dummy string by replacing "return stateC, countyC, cityC" in get_params.pyx to "return 'hellos','hellocounty','hellocity'" and it did return and print out "hellos" correctly as it should. The c api retrieves the strings from a database which then returns them to django when calling the method onn the model. Does that mean this is a problem with the database encoding? I didnt think of that because i just figured if my python standalone script ran correctly but the django api call did not, it meant that it had to do something with django.

Comment: Django convert's any given string to `Unicode` because it works with Unicode string, seems to me Django is trying to convert it but is using `utf-8` as the encoding which it may not be. Try this: check what's the database encoding and try to return the dommy string (only ascii) from C instead of python. To make sure is a problem with encodings in your formed string.

Comment: By trying to return the dummy string from C do you mean write an example script to call the api and print out the string? Else, im not sure what you mean. If that is what you mean I can confirm it does work properly. Already wrote the C example to call the api and print the string returned which it does correctly.

Comment: By returning a dummy string from C I was referring to modify the C code. Inside the method you're calling write: return "hello from c". If you can't modify the code, forget about it, you will need to figure out what's the encoding your C code is yielding by: *checking database encoding*

Comment: Ok, I will determine what type of encoding C is yielding but is there a reason why running the standalone python script works with the C api call but not with django? Does it make sense that if this is the case that I should still be concerned with the type of encoding C/database is using considering we already know it works with python in this way?

Comment: It makes sense as I pointed above. Django automatically converts any string into **Unicode**, a regular Python's script doesn't. That's why you see the call to `force_unicode` in your Traceback. That is Django doing the conversion. It will make the difference if we already knew the encoding, because in the same method when the API is called (Python side) you can return it directly decoded in Unicode (specifying the encode it's using) so Django won't mess with it.

Comment: Instead of this: `return stC` we can do something like this: `return stC.decode('the buffer encoding')`. I just assuming it will work, maybe it doesn't :) Is a very specific and a little hard problem :)